# search in array for string

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to change a string(cities) that contains a value from array(city names).

**Code:**

```
for ($i=0; $i<$1000; $i++) {

$cities = "I live in Prag";  
$array = array("Wien","Prag","Berlin");
foreach ($array AS $val) {

        if (preg_match("/".$val."/", $cities)) {
        $cities = str_replace($val, ", " . $val. ", ", $cities);    
        }
    }
}
```

is there another solution?

thanks

Comment: Is the string always like that? Meaning the cityname is with capital letter?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? Is the code working? There are usually always more than one way to do certain things.

Comment: strange replacement ... what value should `Prag` replace with?

Comment: no the string is changing. Because I want to keep the example simple as possible!  I read the cities from mysql database out.

Comment: show the expected result

Comment: i just want to put "," before and after the string if there is a match

Comment: When this code runs, the result becomes `I live in , Prag,` is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `preg_replace` and `implode` functions:

```
$cities = "I live in Prag but love Wien";
$array = array("Wien","Prag","Berlin");
$cities = preg_replace("/\b". implode("|", $array) ."\b/", ',$0,', $cities);

print_r($cities);  // "I live in ,Prag, but love ,Wien,"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find keys of the values that match the criteria, then you need to loop over the array so use like this.

```
$example = array('An example','Another example','One Example','Last example');
$searchword = 'last';
$matches = array();
foreach($example as $k=>$v) {
    if(preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $v)) {
        $matches[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: i try the example from Gorakh!

Answer (score 0):

I think...

```
$cities = "I live in Prag";  
$array = array("Wien","Prag","Berlin");
foreach ($array AS $val) {

    $cities = preg_replace("/(.*)(" . $val . ")(.*)/", "$1, $2, $3", $cities);
}

Echo $cities;
```

Could do it.

Edit working example: https://3v4l.org/0eDDW

Comment: i think the example from Gorakh could be the solution what i need. But the other way round, namely the cities in the array are the strings that should be found in the variable cities.

Comment: @Erik So?? What does that have to do with my answer? Is not my answer correct?